# PHP file_put_contents() make a primary key that auto_increments

Tags: php, primary-key, auto-increment, file-put-contents

this is my first time asking a question since I cant find any better solutions for my problem. I got a task to make a form by website that uses file_put_contents() for book data library.
My code contains:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $file = "dataBuku.txt";
    if (file_exists($file) && filesize($file) > 0) {
        $getContent = file_get_contents($file);
        if (preg_match_all('/Kode Buku: (\d+)/', $getContent, $matches)) {
            $kode = $matches[1];
            $kodeAkhir = max($kode);
            $kodeBuku = $kodeAkhir + 1;
        }
    } else {
        $kodeBuku = 1;
    }
    $judul = $_POST['judul'];
    $pengarang = $_POST['pengarang'];
    $tahunTerbit = $_POST['tahunTerbit'];
    $halaman = $_POST['halaman'];
    $penerbit = $_POST['penerbit'];
    $kategori = $_POST['kategori'];

    $dataBuku = "Kode Buku: $kodeBuku" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Judul Buku: $judul" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Pengarang Buku: $pengarang" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Tahun Terbit Buku: $tahunTerbit" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Halaman Buku: $halaman" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Penerbit Buku: $penerbit" . PHP_EOL;
    $dataBuku .= "Kategori Buku: $kategori" . PHP_EOL;
    
    if ($_FILES['cover']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $ekstensiFile = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['cover']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $namaFile = $kodeBuku . "_" . $pengarang . "_" . $judul . "." . $ekstensiFile;
        $namaSementara = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
        $lokasiFile = 'cover/' . $namaFile;
        move_uploaded_file($namaSementara, $lokasiFile);
    }

    $dataBuku .= "Cover Buku: $lokasiFile" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

    if (file_put_contents($file, $dataBuku, FILE_APPEND) > 0){
        echo "<p> Data Written successfully </p>";
    }else{
        echo "<p> Data Written failed </p>";
    }

    $fileIndiv = "$kodeBuku - $judul - $pengarang.txt";

    if (file_put_contents($fileIndiv, $dataBuku) > 0){
        echo "<p> $fileIndiv Written successfully </p>";
    }else{
        echo "<p> Data Written failed </p>";
    }
}

echo "<br> <a href='tes.php'><button>Back</button></a>";
echo "<br> <a href='cek.php'><button>Cek Data</button></a>"
?>
```

With the expected output:

Kode Buku: 1 (auto_increment)

Judul Buku: Harga Sebuah Percaya

Pengarang Buku: Tere Liye

Tahun Terbit Buku: 2017

Halaman Buku: 302

Penerbit Buku: Mahaka Publishing

Kategori Buku: Novel

Cover Buku: cover/1_Tere Liye_Harga Sebuah Percaya.jpg

Sorry, it's all in Indonesian, but Im sure you'll get the point, tho. I wanted to make the most effective that can auto_increment the 'kodeBuku' without that long code block, reply below if you have any thoughts, will be appreciated, Thanks.

kodeBuku become auto_increment that not counting for lines but the last kodeBuku + 1

Comment: Files are not the best way to do this. Files get locked and overwritten, and you'll run into access issues depending on how busy your site is. A database is the best way to store data with auto incrementing records.

Comment: Lots of red flags that scream "doing it the hard way". You are effectively creating your own "database" by using the file system. If your host doesn't support a database such as MySQL, get a different host. If that's not an option, use SQLite. To your auto-increment, whenever a client "requires" that, they'll almost always also "require" that "holes" be filled someday in the future so that the number are contiguous, and that's just messy. Ideally the ID should be opaque, and an UUID is a great choice and if you are forced to work without a real database, should work much better at least